# How do I pass a post value from a form element on a parent form to a child form?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the value from the parent form into the child; not the other way around. Found many a howto from child to parent but that doesn't work for me. I have an onclick event in the input button but I'm unsure how to get the value from this calendar into the child window from here.

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <p style="padding:10px;">
    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="" maxlength="10"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="g_Calendar.show(event, 'date', 'yyyy-mm-dd')" title="Show Calendar" style="text-decoration:none;"> <img src="calendar.gif" class="cp_img" alt="Open Calendar" style="padding-bottom:3px;"></a><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit" onclick="popWindow('search.php')">
  </p>
 </form>
```

Comment: Jack, when the function popWindow is called, you can get the date value and then append it to the path that's being provided as the parameter:

var dateVal = document.getElementById("date");
window.open(param + "?dateValue=" + dateVal);

Comment: Kirtan, I am sooo javascript retarded it's not even funny. :)  It truly sounds like it will work but how.. Is there a tut somewhere that you can point me to so that I can get this working? Or maybe a snippet of code? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: See my updated answer for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QueryStrings like this -

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Submit" onclick="popWindow('search.php')">
```

You can read the QueryString values using utilities like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JSCookieQueryStrWrapper.aspx).

### EDIT

```
function popWindow(windowUrl) {
    var dateVal = document.getElementById("date").value;
    window.open(windowUrl + "?dateValue=" + dateVal); //This will open the window with the URL like search.php?dateValue=1/1/09.
}
```

Comment: Hi Kirtan, thanks. Will the value of the date input be appended **before** the user presses the button or afterward? If it is afterward, this won't work. At least I don't think it will.

Comment: Kirtan.. Thank you! I at least have the value in the window now. I have another question if you wouldn't mind. I already have a javascript script to open a window. Can I replace your window.open code and replace it with my code and still have it work or is the window.open needed?

Comment: Kirtan, thank you. I got it! Thank you! I really have to learn some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening a window using window.open you can pass value to it using

1. Querystring

like

```
search.php?ValueToPass=value
```

and read from the popup using

```
Request.QueryString["ValueToPass"]
```

or read value from pop up using

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener) object.

This returns a reference to the window that opened this current window.

Eg:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('<%=text.ClientID%>').value
```

***Edit:***

From PHP you can get the querystring variable. Take a look at

[PHP $_GET Function](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp)

Comment: Hi Phoenix and thanks for the help. I think that Kirtan is suggesting the same thing. Yes, I'm using window.open but my question is: will the value of the date calendar be appended after or before the user presses the submit button?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that if I can append a querystring onto the filename, I dhould be able to use PHP to test for the GET var. Yes?

Comment: Yes you can access the querystring variable in PHP.